# python: map( new object, [arguments] )

Tags: python

I want to create an array with objects, using `map` function:

```
class Something:
    def __init__( self, number ):
        ...

def new_object( x ):
    return Something(x)

map( new_object, [1,2,3,4] )
```

Is there default python syntax equivalent to `new_object`? something like `Something.new(x)`, that I could pass to map?

(I don't ask for `lambda` function, I ask for some built-in class-level function. I just want to avoid this `new_object` if there is a built-in equivalent)

Comment: Did you even try just passing the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straightforwardly:

```
map( Something, [1,2,3,4] )
```

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna post.